# How to get the tag number in BER-TLV?

Tags: networking, bit, tlv

I have such a question, let's say the tag consists of 2 bytes `10011111 01110110`

In training articles or videos, they say that in this case the B5-B1 bits in the first byte and B1-B7 of the second byte are considered the tag number.

Do i understand correctly that, based on the example, the number will be `1111 1111011`, that is, 2043?

Or does it work in the sense that `1111 + 1111011` is 15 + 123 = 138?

Or does it generally work like this - `10011111 01110110`, that is, 40822?

Or by analogy `10011111 + 01110110` i.e. 159 + 118 = 277?